# C++ Tree could not insert value

Tags: c++, tree

I have written this code. But it does not insert and print value. Can anyone check and tell the problem?

```
struct Node{

    int value;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};

class Tree {

Node* root;

public:
Tree insertNode( Node* tree,int val)
{
    if(tree==NULL)
    {
    tree = new Node;
    tree->value=val;
    tree->left=NULL;
    tree->right=NULL;

    }
    else if (val<=tree->value){ 
    insertNode(tree->left,val);
    }
    else
    {
        insertNode(tree->right,val);
    }

    return *this;
}


insert(int val)
{
    insertNode(root, val);

}

void printTree(Node* root)
{


    if(!root)
    {
        cout<<"Tree is empty"<<endl;
        return;
    }

    printTree(root->left);
    cout<<root->value;
    printTree(root->right);


}


print()
{
    printTree(this->root);
}


};



int main(){


Tree* Nodd = new Tree();
Nodd->insert(12);
Nodd->insert(10);
Nodd->print();


}
```

When i run this program it, just run in the first if statement in the insertNode function. I think, i am missing something and doing something wrong.

Comment: I would use a debugger, but mine is not working at the moment.  Could you run this through a debugger and edit your post with your findings?

Comment: When you pass parameters *by value*, you can't change their values on the receiving end.  The caller's variable will be unchanged.  Maybe you should pass by reference?

Comment: `Tree::root` is uninitialized - you should have a constructor that sets it to `nullptr`. `insertNode()` takes the `tree` parameter by value, so modifying it in that function has no effect.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I recommend searching the internet for "c++ binary tree example" to find some examples to compare your code with.

Comment: When you are passing root to insert node function, you are passing it by value, when you created new node, it wasn't assigned to root. You will have to pass it by reference, like Tree insertNode( Node* &tree, int val). Your return type shouldn't be tree.

Answer (score 1):

`Tree insertNode( Node* tree,int val)` 
In this function you should pass the node pointer by reference to be able to modify the node, so the correct parameter is 
 `Tree insertNode( Node* &tree,int val)`

Comment: Did you just copy my comment?

Comment: Thanks Wala Saif. I passed by reference. Now it works